# Field A in the Power Apps should be only visible AND required if Field B (Number) starts with 6 or 7 in power app

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas, formula

Field A in the Power Apps should be only visible AND required if Field B (Number) starts with 6 or 7 in power app.

Comment: What are the controls used for field A and field B? Can you add screenshots if possible?

Comment: Hi @ABC, did you try below solution? Is it working for you or you still need any help with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use formula like below to check if number is starting with 6 or 7:

```
StartsWith(varNumber, 6) || StartsWith(varNumber, 7)
```

**OR**

```
StartsWith(Text(varNumber), "6") || StartsWith(Text(varNumber), "7")
```

Where `varNumber` is the value of your number field.

You can use such formula on `Visible` property of control to show/hide it. Also, if you are using [data card control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/controls/control-card), you can use same formula for `Required` property of data card. If not using data cards, you have to check if there is any value in field A or not on submit of form / on click of button control

**Example**:

Here I am showing/hiding button based on value in text input:

[image]

I have set `Visible` property of button control to:

```
StartsWith(TextInput1.Text, 6) || StartsWith(TextInput1.Text, 7)
```

Comment: I'm checking the progress of this issue. Did Ganesh Sanap 's answer help you?